# Не работает контактная форма на HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html5

Ребят помогите разобраться почему не работает контактная форма при отправке сообщений.
Код самой формы на HTML файла index.html, файл лежит в корне на хостинге:

```
<div class="card card-hero animated fadeInUp animation-delay-7">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal contact-form-with-recaptcha" role="form">
              <fieldset class="container">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="name" autocomplete="false" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Имя"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="email" autocomplete="false" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="subject" autocomplete="false" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Тема"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение..."></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Код PHP обработчика, который лежит в папке /php/email-sender.php
Сам код:

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');

$Recipient = 'TESTTESTTES@gmail.com'; // 

if($Recipient) {

    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $Message = $_POST['message'];
    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $Category = $_POST['category'];
    }

    $Email_body = "";
    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $Email_body .= "From: " . $Name . "\n" .
                                    "Email: " . $Email . "\n" .
                                    "Subject: " . $Subject . "\n" .
                                    "Message: " . $Message . "\n" .
                                    "Category: " . $Category . "\n";
    } else {
        $Email_body .= "From: " . $Name . "\n" .
                                    "Email: " . $Email . "\n" .
                                    "Subject: " . $Subject . "\n" .
                                    "Message: " . $Message . "\n";
    }

    $Email_headers = "";
    $Email_headers .= 'From: ' . $Name . ' <' . $Email . '>' . "\r\n".
                      "Reply-To: " .  $Email . "\r\n";

    $sent = mail($Recipient, $Subject, $Email_body, $Email_headers);

    if ($sent){
        $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'yes');
    } else{
        $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'no');
    }

    echo json_encode($emailResult);

} else {

    $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'no');
    echo json_encode($emailResult);

}
?>
```

При нажатии кнопки submit страница перезагружается и не отправляет е-майл. С хостингом проблем нет и порты открыты, скорее всего где то я допустил ошибку, помогите разобраться.

Comment: `<form class="form-horizontal contact-form-with-recaptcha" role="form" action="/php/email-sender.php">`

Comment: скрипт запускается но не передает данные из формы - решение не верное (

Comment: Ну почему же, наоборот. У вас в форме не указан скрипт-обработчик, т.е. запрос уходит в никуда. Другой вопрос, что его надо указать с учетом путей. Например <form class="form-horizontal contact-form-with-recaptcha" role="form" action="http://<?= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/php/email-sender.php"> если ваш запрос приходит по пути http://site_name.com/php/email-sender.php

Comment: @Artem, как вам написали в комментарии выше, укажите полный путь до php-скрипта. Также добавьте тегу `form` атрибут `method="post"`.